# Laravel cannot verify email due to user are not authenticated

Tags: php, laravel

TLDR; I use Valet, and mailhog for the email testing. This is just basic sign up form. User are not authenticated even if in the register path, they have been logged in right after the user instance has been created.

In POST /register controller

```
Auth::login($user= User::create([...])); <-- here we login the user right after the user created.
event(new Registered($user));
```

Then, when user click the verification email, this happened:

```
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}',function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
 // user is not authenticated, thus redirected again to login route.
 // this happened again and again when we click the link from email verification,
// even though we are "logged in" in the session
})->middleware(['auth','signed',...]);
```

Can anyone help with this? This is Laravel Version: 8.32.1 & PHP Version: 8.0.0
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure the that it's actually creating a user when you try to authenticate them? You should be checking for null before attempting the login. Once you are able to verify that the record was created and stored, only then should you attempt to log them in.